# HMR settings not changing in laravel vite

Tags: laravel, vite, web-development-server, laravel-vite, hmr

I'm using laravel 10, 
and i want to use vite to load my assets, however the app calls `https://localhost:3000` for the hmr server, My desired behavior is for it to connect to `http://localhost:3000` as i have no live server using https plus its hard to get a key and cert for it. 
I tried changing the host, port and protocol in vite.config.js but to no avail. 
is there any way to make the laravel app call to
`http://localhost:3000` for hmr?

[image]?